# npm install redis problems

Tags: node.js, redis, hiredis

Having problems running npm install redis.  Got error:

```
npm WARN install Refusing to install redis as a dependency of itself
```

When I tried to install hiredis it would appear to install just fine however, when I tried to run any of the examples they would fail with the required file "redis" not found.

I did finally solve this by installing redis global or:

```
npm install -g redis
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I've seen that when the name of the project I'm working on matches the name of a module I'm installing via npm.

Answer (score 10):

Ensure your app `package.json` name is not **redis**.

---

*Good package.json*

```
{
  "name": "redis-app"
  //...
}
```

*Bad package.json*

```
{
  "name": "redis"
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Matthew's comment is correct. This error will occur when your folder name is the same as an NPM module. So just change your folder name from redis to redisApp or something.